# CSS: ui-icon inside ui-widget-header not inheriting color

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to create list using jQuery ui classes.

**Problem is**

```
<span class="ui-corner-all ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span>
```

is inside `ui-widget-header` both `<div>` and `<a>` but icons colors do not inherit widget-header text color.

Kindly help in making this this list UI-Theme-compatible, my requirement is that list should have 2 icons at both ends and icon containers should be different as I have used `ui-widget-header`  but any other solution is welcome.

**From jquery ui.css**

```
.ui-widget-header {
    background: url("images/ui-bg_glass_25_cb842e_1x400.png") repeat-x scroll 50% 50% #CB842E;
    border: 1px solid #D49768;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE:** [jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/MNe4s/15](http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/MNe4s/15)

**CSS:**

```
.ui-splitselect{font-size:.8em}
.ui-splitselect ul{-moz-user-select:none}
.ui-splitselect div.list-selected{float:left;border:none;margin:0;padding:0}
.ui-splitselect div.list-available{float:left;border-top:none;border-bottom:none;border-right:none;margin:0;padding:0}
.ui-splitselect ul.list{position:relative;overflow:auto;overflow-x:hidden;list-style:none;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0}
.ui-splitselect li{cursor:default;line-height:20px;height:20px;font-size:11px;list-style:none;display:list-item;white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;margin:1px;padding:0}
.ui-splitselect li .handle-select{float:left}
.ui-splitselect li .handle-drag{float:left;height:20px;border-top:0;border-bottom:0;margin:0 10px 0 5px;padding:2px 5px}
.ui-splitselect li .handle-move{text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer;float:right;height:20px;border-top:0;border-bottom:0;margin:0 5px 0 10px;padding:2px 5px}
.ui-splitselect li.ui-state-focus .handle-drag,.ui-splitselect li.ui-state-focus .handle-move{border:inherit;border-top:0;border-bottom:0}
.ui-splitselect .ui-widget-header{border:none;font-size:11px}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="ui-splitselect ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <div class="ui-widget-content list-available" style="width: 200px;">
        <ul class="list available" style=" ">
            <li class="ui-state-default">
                <div class='handle-drag ui-widget-header'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-carat-2-n-s'></span></div>
                <span class="handle-select">Espania</span>
                                <a class="handle-move ui-widget-header" href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want to change the color of? The background, or the icon? If it's the icon then you'll need to specify a different image file, as all the icons on that are blue...

Comment: ...or you could use an icon font, if you can find one with the symbols you need...